# Finding an explicit Radon-Nikodym derivative

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $f_{1}, f_{2} \in L^{1}(X)$. Define two signed measures $\nu_{1}, \nu_{2}$ on $(X, \mathcal{M})$ by $\nu_{1}(E) = \displaystyle\int_{E} f_{1} d\mu$ and $\nu_{2}(E) = \displaystyle\int_{E} f_{2} d\mu$ for every $E \in \mathcal{M}$. Suppose that $\nu_{1} \ll \nu_{2}$ and $\nu_{2} \ll \nu_{1}$. Find the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d \nu_{1}}{d \nu_{2}}$ explicitly, that is find an explicit function $g$ suach that $\nu_{1} (E) = \displaystyle\int_{E} g d \nu_{2}$ for every $E \in \mathcal{M}$.

My first attempt was trying to prove the existence of a function $h$ such that $\mu(E) = \displaystyle\int_{E} h d\nu_{2}$ so that $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu_{2}} = h$ because if such a function exists then we can apply the well known chain rule for Radon-Nikodym derviatives to conclude that $\frac{d \nu_{1}}{d \nu_{2}} = \frac{d \nu_{1}}{d \mu} \frac{d \mu}{d \nu_{2}}$ and $\frac{d \mu}{d \nu_{2}} = \left( \frac{d \nu_{2}}{d \mu} \right) ^{-1} = \frac{1}{f_{2}}$ a.e. Such a function would exist if $\mu \ll \nu_{2}$, so I also tried to prove that without any success. I also tried to find the required Radon-Nikodym derivative in the easiest possible case which is when $f_{1} \equiv \chi_{_{A}}$ and $f_{2} \equiv \chi_{_{B}}$ for some measurable sets $A$ and $B$ of finite measure (since $f_{1}, f_{2} \in L^{1}(X)$), but I couldn't find a function $g$ with the desired property. Maybe this is not even the best way in which the problem can be solved, so any hints or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all for your responses.